# For loop in functional style

Tags: loops, for-loop, functional-programming

In functional programming books, a recurring theme is that FP means telling computer what to do, not how to do. And some code example is give, like:

```
val newNumbers = oldNumbers.map(_ * 2)
```

Explanation is given that we dont implement this using traditional `for-loop`, but we rather use `map`.

But isn't `map` internally implementing for loop. So we have just moved for loop from our code to some other part.
So how exactly it makes FP better than imperative style?

Comment: It hides and abstracts the implementation, rather than always re-implementing it

Comment: A `for` loop is internally implemented by a `jump` instruction (goto). But you wouldn't give up loops and use gotos everywhere just because that's how loops are implemented.

Comment: @Apocalisp This should be the accepted comment :D

Comment: @Apocalisp, can you please elaborate your answer more?

Comment: Sometimes it's a loop. Sometimes it's farming out different pieces to different CPUs, or even different cluster nodes. Part of the value is that this decision no longer needs to be made up-front; things can be distributed against nodes / cluster members / etc. transparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, and may indeed be an answer.

I'll borrow from Apocalisp's comment:

> A for loop is internally implemented by a jump instruction (goto). But you wouldn't give up loops and use gotos everywhere just because that's how loops are implemented

We don't use GOTO (or longjmp/setjmp) anymore for the following reasons:

1. It's too hard to follow control flow.
2. They're error-prone and difficult to use properly.

Instead we use `for`, `while`, etc. (and yes, `map`). It's clearer what we *mean*, and it's harder (though I'd still argue far too easy) to make a mistake with these constructs.

> How does it prove that FP scores over imperative style? I can very well put imperative implementation inside a well coded method, and call it wherever I need

Yes, you could do that. You shouldn't, for the same reason you should use generally prefer well-tested and popular 3rd party libraries or built-in language constructs to rolling everything yourself. Even if you're an awesome developer you can't compete with e.g. writers of popular compilers (which tend to be some of the best people in the field) or hundreds of contributors fixing edge-case bugs in a popular open source library.

> I can implement a method imperatively which returns a new list without modifying input one, and call this method wherever I need

Yes. Again, You can do that. But consider the following:

```
function doubleEvery(arr) {
  let i;
  let l = arr.length;
  let result = [];
  for (i=0; i<length; ++i) {
    result.push(arr[i] * 2);
  }

  return result;
}
```

What could go wrong?

```
function doubleEvery(arr) { // iterating is coupled to doubling
  let i; // unitialized variable
  let l = arr.length;

  // Have to allocate result object, no opportunity for compiler
  // to optimize it away or use structural sharing
  let result = [];
  for (i=0; i<length; ++i) { // possible off-by-one error

    // Here if it's a more complex operation than simply doubling
    // we can't just pull this part out to test it independently
    result.push(arr[i] * 2);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Plus the original is 9 lines, compared to `arr.map(x => x * 2)`. That's a 90% LoC savings which is easier on tools, networks, and disks.

What I think Apocalisp is pointing out is that the argument you are making is vulnerable to a *reductio ad absurdum*: it could be applied to *any* abstraction. What man? You write *syntax*? [*Real* programmers write](https://xkcd.com/378/) opcodes in straight binary yo.

Comment: You surely enlightened me.Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Mandroid you're welcome. Thanks for being open to being enlightened and asking the question in good faith!

Answer (score 2):

## Declerative and Imperative

Let's stay with your example and let's double all values.

1. Imperative

   - Computer, go from the first to the last index, increasing the current index each time it is smaller than the length of the array. If the current index is smaller, double the current index and add it to the new array, or we'll return the new array.

     ```
     function double(arr) {
        newArray = []
        for(index = 0; index < arr.length; i++) {
            newArr.push(arr[index] * 2) 
        }
        return newArray
     }
     ```
2. Declerative

   - Computer, please give me a new array where all values are doubled

     ```
     arr.map(double)
     ```

## Implemation

The map function hides and abstracts the implementation instead of re-implementing it over and over again. As a map user, I am not interested in whether the function was realized with a loop, a recursion or perhaps in a completely different programming language.

> The main point is that it has to do its job properly.

```js
const map = fn => xs => {
  let newArray = []
  for(let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
    newArray.push( fn(xs[i]) )
  }
  return newArray
}

const double = x =>
  x * 2

console.log(
  map (double) ([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
```

```js
const map = fn => xs =>
  _map (fn) (xs) ([])

const _map = fn => xs => ys =>
  xs.length === 0
    ? ys
    : _map (fn) (xs.slice(1)) (ys.concat( fn(xs[0]) ))
      
const double = x =>
  x * 2
      
console.log(
  map (double) ([1, 2, 3, 4])
)
```

Comment: It's a bit unfair to compare a `for` loop with `map`, because the latter is less expressive. You cannot hide the recursion in all cases.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with _unfair_.. Additionally it was not my goal to hide the recursion but to creating the same function call for the user - but thank you for this hint!

Comment: `map` covers only a subset of the iterative algorithms you can express with a `for` loop. You have to use other iterative higher order functions or even resort to explicit recursion to cover them all. All iterative higher order functions are used to replace explicit recursion - that's what I meant with _hide recursion_.

Comment: How does it prove that FP scores over imperative style? I can very well put imperative implementation inside a well coded method, and call it wherever I need.

Comment: @Mandroid Choosing a paradigm is not about which one is "better". It is about your preferred way of reasoning. If you prefer math, use FP. If you prefer classical software engineering, use OOP. If you feel comfortable in both fields, use both.

Answer (score 1):

> But isn't map function internally implementing for loop

Not usually (in functional languages at least). In some of the less multi-paradigmy functional languages, for loops don't even exist.

A common implementation of `map` is this:

```
map(f, []) = []
map(f, x::xs) = f(x) :: map(f, xs)
```

> So how exactly it makes FP better than imperative style?

Because, even if `map` happens to be implemented with a for loop, the code that uses `map` can be written without any mutable variables or data structures.

So instead of putting a list into a mutable variable and reassigning it from within the loop or, even worse, using a mutable list into which you insert elements from the for loop, you can have an immutable variable containing an immutable list and it just works, no matter what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: I can implement a method imperatively which returns a new list without modifying input one, and call this method wherever I need.

Comment: @Mandroid your missing the point. Why do I need a library? I could just write all that code myself. Why do I need tests? I made sure my code works, if my coworkers change it its on them to make sure they don't break any of the 5,682 most common execution paths through it. The point is that you don't 1) have to do the work and 2) ensure that it continues to work.